# Failure to retrieve data from SQLite on ListView

Tags: android

I want to show data from database on the ListView, and I tried to use rawQuery and query to do it.

It is okay to show the data by the rawQuery, but it has nothing happen by query after button pressed. The application can be executed without error, and just failure to show the data by query.

I have it googled and checked on Android developer for some hints, but seem the guide should be followed. I would appreciate if someone could let me know what went wrong when I use query to get data. Why data not show on the ListView?

Update#
I tried to change the selection as below, but still can't retrieve the data

1st change:selection changed, selection args = null

```
String selection = "Phone=1234567890";
Cursor cursor = dbRead.query(ContactContract.ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                                        projection, selection, null, null, null, sortOrder);
```

2nd change:

```
String selection = "Phone=?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"1234567890"};
Cursor cursor = dbRead.query(ContactContract.ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                                        projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```

Here is the listener:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout Layout_record = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_record);
        ListView listView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
        Button btn = (Button) v;
        Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        Button btn_count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_count);
        Button btn_showAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_showAll);
        TextView tv_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
        ContactDBHelper mDBHelper = new ContactDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase dbWrite = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase dbRead = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                ContactContract.ContactEntry._ID,
                ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME,
                ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE
        };

        String selection = "_ID=? OR Contact=? OR PHONE=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"ID", "Contact", "Phone"};
        String sortOrder = ContactContract.ContactEntry._ID + " DESC";

        String queryAll = "SELECT * FROM " + ContactContract.ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME;

        if(btn==btn_submit) {

            EditText et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
            EditText et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone);

            String dataName = et_name.getText().toString();
            String dataPhone = et_phone.getText().toString();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME, dataName);
            values.put(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE, dataPhone);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dbWrite.insert(ContactContract.ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (btn==btn_count) {

        } else {
//          Cursor cursor = dbRead.rawQuery(queryAll,null);
            Cursor cursor = dbRead.query(ContactContract.ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                                        projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long itemID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactContract.ContactEntry._ID));
                String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME));
                int contactPhone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE));

                String row = itemID + "-" + contactName + "~" + contactPhone;
                adapter.add(row);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Layout_record.addView(listView);
            dbRead.close();

        }
    }
```

Here is the database contract
    public class ContactContract {
    public ContactContract() {}

```
public static abstract class ContactEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ContactBook";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME= "Contact";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE = "Phone";

    public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    public static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    ContactEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE + TEXT_TYPE +
                    " )";

    public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME;
}
```

}

Comment: dont use `ArrayAdapter` as your data model is sqlite db, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: Okay, I will try to use SimpleCursorAdapter, but I am wondering whether ArrayAdapter doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your selection (I don't know your table columns, etc.) but these two lines:

```
    String selection = "_ID=? OR Contact=? OR PHONE=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"ID", "Contact", "Phone"};
```

mean:

```
    Select * from TABLE WHERE _ID="ID" OR Contact="Contact" OR PHONE="Phone";
```

I don't think that's what you mean... maybe try a selection without any arguments and then try to find a row by ID. Then a row by Contact (whatever that column is supposed to represent).

EDIT:

In addition to that problem, you are probably not entering data with your `insert` statement. Your primary key `_ID` does not auto increment, so your insert will fail, so change your create statement to:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                ContactEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE + TEXT_TYPE +
                " )";
```

You could also manually add the `_ID` as in:

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactContract.ContactEntry._ID, dataId);
        values.put(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_NAME, dataName);
        values.put(ContactContract.ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT_PHONE, dataPhone);
```

Also, note that your "delete" drops the table. You probably should just delete all rows as in `DELETE * FROM TABLE_NAME` or something.

Comment: the selection args are there to reduce the number of results - it is not a "search", it is based on "equivalence" which means the above will only return rows where the column PHONE is equal to the string "Phone" - to "search" you need PHONE="1234567890" or something like that...

Comment: I have tried to change the selection and query, and I have updated the change  to the post. However, it is still failure to retrieve the data(from the column with phone number 1234567890), and I have checked that the phone is there. What I want to do now is try to get the specific row data from the database(including ID,Contact name, Phone).